# Dotnet-test-explorer Path For Result File | Not Creating a File

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, test-explorer

I have a C# project in Visual Studio Code.

I was experimenting with the following configuration setting for the .NET Core Test Explorer (version v0.7.8):

[image]

I ran a test from the Test Explorer.
Results were shown in the consoles.

But when I went to the path below, there was no file created.

Am I using the setting correctly?

When I select the context menu to `Copy setting as JSON`  by clicking the gear icon in the picture, I get this:

```
"dotnet-test-explorer.pathForResultFile": "c:\\Users\\guyl\\results.txt"
```

I also tried

```
"c:\\Users\\guyl\\"
```

and

```
"c:\\Users\\guyl"
```

I also installed **Test Explorer UI** v2.21.1 (hbenl.vscode-test-explorer).  This is supposed to work hand-in-hand with the above.

##### Other Things Attempted

###### 1.

Tried adding this to the `tasks.json` file:

```
        {
            "label": "test",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "-l:html;LogFileName=testOutput.html"
            ]
        }
```

But the test runner is only running the "build" task.
I do not know how to run the "test" task, except from the **Terminal** menu.